# Hiding Table elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 row table – the top row is a single column and the 2nd row is 3 columns.

Each of the 4 “table cells”  has a graphic and a caption, and is assigned the same class

I want to be able to click on any of the 4 cells, hide the contents of all 4 cells, and replace them with new content based on which ever cell is clicked on.

I can get it to work (using the show and hide methods) for the 3 cells that are all in the 2nd table row, by assigning each of them the same td class, but can’t figure out how to make the single, top row cell clickable so that it will hide the bottom 3, or click any of the bottom 3 and hide the top row cell along with the other 2 from the second row.

Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery?

**Update with Code**

Sorry for not posting the code. Am brand new at this and had only gotten so far, but now understand why you'd want to see it...:-)

Here's what I have so far. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide().filter('.top').show();
    $('.box h1').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().siblings().hide();
        $(this).siblings().show().last();
        $(this).siblings('a.up-link').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().hide().filter('h1').show();
            $(this).parent().siblings(':not(h1)').show();
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td class="box top">
        <h1 style="background-image:url(blue.jpg);width:275px;height:230px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <p class="caption-2">
            Topic 1
        </p>
        </h1>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Answer 1</h1>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="box top">
        <h1 style="background-image:url(blue.jpg);width:275px;height:230px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <p class="caption-2">
            Topic 2
        </p>
        </h1>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Answer 2</h1>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="box top">
        <h1 style="background-image:url(blue.jpg);width:275px;height:230px; background- repeat:no-repeat;">
        <p class="caption-2">
            Topic 3
        </p>
        </h1>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Answer 3</h1>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="box top">
        <h1 style="background-image:url(blue.jpg);width:275px;height:230px; background- repeat:no-repeat;">
        <p class="caption-2">
            Topic 4
        </p>
        </h1>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Answer 4</h1>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's your HTML? *Showing* us is *always* better than *describing* it at us.

Comment: you must show to us what have you tried

Comment: Sounds like you've already made some progress on the code, don't hesitate to post it, we all love to help!

Comment: Guys, wait for his update with code, don't vote him down precipitatedly!!

Comment: @David Thomas Sorry for not posting the code. Am brand new at this and had only gotten so far, but now understand why you'd want to see it...:-) I've updated the question with the code. Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles  Sorry for not posting the code. Am brand new at this and had only gotten so far, but now understand why you'd want to see it...:-) I've updated the question with the code. Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Comment: @tymeJV  Sorry for not posting the code. Am brand new at this and had only gotten so far, but now understand why you'd want to see it...:-) I've updated the question with the code. Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for sticking up for the newbie...:-)

Comment: @user2316544 Some people here love to push down sometimes.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The good news is, NOW I know...:-)

Comment: Why are Topics 2 - 4 in the same row, but Topic 1 is on a row by itself? Is that intentional?

Comment: @bbird Yes it is. Topic 1 is the width of Topics 2-4 combined. Picture a slide show with 3 thumbnails under it. It's not a slide show, but that's the layout.

Comment: Ok, so each row is kind of a section, with n number of topics per row?

Comment: @bbird Yes. And they will have the same number of topics. Basically this is exactly what we started with, but instead of beginning with a list of links, there are 4 clickable graphics that are each in their own cell in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is precisely what you're looking for (and it's not nest-able like the answer to your other question with the `<div>` structure), but the following will make your topics clickable and reveal their associated answer whilst hiding the other topics. Also, the answers are clickable to go back up and reveal all the topics again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('td > :not(h1)').hide(); //hide the immediate children that aren't h1 of each td
        $('td > h1').click(function () { //make the immediate h1 child of the td (aka the Topic) clickable
            $('td > h1').hide(); //hide the topic when clicked
            $(this).next('div.box').show().off('click').click(function () { //show the answer box, unbind any previous click handler, add click handler that will reset it back to the way it was
                $(this).hide();
                $('td > h1').show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it in the morning. When you say it's not nestable , do you mean it can only go down one level (as opposed to the multiple levels we had with the other approach) ? If not , is there a way to combine the 2 approaches?

Comment: Correct, it only operates at one level. Unless you intend to nest tables with in table cells (not generally recommended), it might be a little tricky to combine the approaches.

Comment: Thanks. Will have to rethink things on our end, as we do need the multiple levels. The good news is, between your 2 answers (and the accompanying education), I've got a lot of options to work with. Truly can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one method, but a powerful one.

You can put the table into a DIV, and then use jQuery's `.html()` method to replace the entire Div with new content.

Here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XppA6/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <style>
            table, tr, td {border:1px solid green;border-collapse:collapse;padding:5px 5px;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#theTable td').click(function() {
                    var i = $(this).attr('id');

                    if (i == 'r1c3'){
                        $('#theDiv').html('<table id="theTable"><tr><td>Just one cell in this table</td></tr></table>');
                    }else{
                        alert('You clicked: [' + i + ']. Try clicking Row 1 Cell 3');
                    }

                });


            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="theDiv">
        <table id="theTable">
            <tr>
                <td id="r1c1">Row 1, Cell 1</td>
                <td id="r1c2">Row 1, Cell 2</td>
                <td id="r1c3">Row 1, Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="r2c1">Row Two, Cell 1</td>
                <td id="r2c2">Row Two, Cell 2</td>
                <td id="r2c3">Row Two, Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My apologies for not explaining this well, I'm new to jQuery. When I click I want all of the other cells (and the one I clicked) to be hidden and replaced from content that's in my html as opposed to an alert popping up. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay. I half get it ... It really helps when you actually READ what you put in the alert box ... :-) Am I right in assuming that I would just adjust and repeat the same "if statement and remove the alert statement to get it to work with every box or is there a way to combine those statements? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @tymeJV I posted the code requested, but haven't heard back from anyone. I can't figure out how to adapt the answer I had received (prior to posting the code) to what I'm working with. Can you help? Thanks in advance for any help you can be. Still new at this..:-)